# Using a python script to install a software with a custom interactive installer

Tags: python, input, subprocess, popen

I have a program that I would like to automatically install by using a python script.

This program provides their installation file as an .exe file. It can be executed in a linux environment and initially prompts the user whether he would like to install this program and expects a key input `[Y/n]`. Then it are prompts the user to enter `Acknowledged` while showing the terms of service, and afterwards you are asked to specify a few more installation specifications, all through prompting keystrokes.

Is it possible to perform this installation process automatically? I thought about using `subprocess.Popen` to launch the exe, but don't know how to proceed from there and how to provide the correct inputs upon being prompted.

Comment: Is it a GUI based installer or are all these prompts on the command line?

Comment: They are all in the command line, I am using putty to run the installer and it launches a commandline program with no GUI

Comment: You should be able to pass what is needed as stdin to the popen call. Just seperate the individual answers by \n